# Is combining executeCompaction() and executeZOrderBy() in Databricks sensible?

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I'm wondering whether or not it makes sense to combine the two operations.

Let's say I have a `delta_table` from some `.parquet` files. I read them using `DeltaTable.forPath(spark, path)`.

Now I want to do some optimization on the dataset.

I know about the following two optimizations:

1. `delta_table.optimize().executeCompaction()`
2. `delta_table.optimize().executeZOrderBy(some_cols)`

My questions:

1. Does it make sense to combine the operations, in the sense that will my `SQL` perform better on it?
2. Does the order matter?

If there is no clear answer, I will just perform some test queries and time them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manuals:

**executeCompaction()**
Delta Lake on Databricks *can* improve the speed of read queries from a table - the well known small files problem. One way to improve this speed is to coalesce small files into larger ones. Simply faster for Spark. This is operation independent of ZORDERbying as such.

***Caveats**:
If you have a large amount of data and only want to optimize a subset of it, then you can specify an optional partition predicate via WHERE clause so as to reduce the scope. I have a little difficulty on this one, unless partitions are added in order time-wise.*

*For Unity Catalog managed tables, Databricks tunes most of these configurations automatically, if you’re using a SQL endpoint or Databricks Runtime 11.3 LTS or above. So, some manual, some automatic depending on your environment.*

**executeZOrderBy**
Used for 'enhanced' data skipping (WHERE clause), for which 'standard'  data skipping which is standardly applied by Databricks / delta API already and relying on statistics. But you can embellish this all bu ZORDER for high acrdianlity that physically colocates data as opposed to just storing stats.

***Caveats**:* *I seem to remember from somewhere it depends on type of query and small range of data. Expensive operation.*

**Finally** Order of is not an issue as 1) ZORDER works by reducing files, anyway. 2) If doing both on a subset of data, it does not matter if you were applying to non-overlapping parts of the data. If the data  overlaps, then you would do one or the other is my experience on projects done recently.